# Android action button pushed into overflow

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm following the android developers guide. I have this menu I'm inflating in the action bar:

res/menu/main_activity_actions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!--Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:showAsAction="always" />

    <!-- Settings, should always be in overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

I have a corresponding icon in res/drawable, and am inflating like so:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

The problem I'm facing is that the `search` action gets pushed into the overflow, and I can't figure out how to make it an action button that always shows up in the action bar.

**I did not find a duplicate question on this, though there are many related questions.**